# .NET C# Pass IIS app pool credentials as basic authentication Credentials to HTTPRequest

Tags: c#, .net, security

I need to pass IIS app pool credentials as network credentials to a WebAPI call in a .NET application.

```
var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("WEB API URL");
request.Method = "POST";
request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("USERNAME","PASSWORD","DOMAIN");
```

This works fine.

My question is instead of passing hard coded credentials I need to pass IIS app pool credentials as a NetworkCredential object.

I have checked with below code but doesn't work for me.

```
WindowsIdentity identity = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();
using (identity.Impersonate())
{
    var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("WEB API URL");
    request.Method = "POST";
    request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
}
```

Comment: *Don't* use basic authentication in this case. If you want to make a call as a Windows Account (which the pool account is), make sure the service *accepts* Windows authentication. The IIS App Pool user accounts are *special, local* accounts though that aren't visible to other computers on a domain. If you want to call one service from another use domain accounts

Comment: So could u plz guide me how to pass APP POOL user credentials to WEB API.?

Answer (score 0):

There are only 2 options here that I can think of.

**Change your authentication type to Windows authentication**

You can often change this through your project. When you create a new project it will even ask if you'd like to authenticate users via Windows authentication.

**Link up with Active Directory**

Some organisations / companies will use Active Directory to manage their users. This is what allows you to log into specific machines in the office, or limits you to a single workstation, or lets the IT admins reset your password when you forget etc. It's an amazing tool, but a pain in the neck to work with. I'd recommend using a virtualized network using virtual machines to accomplish this.